# writing csv with python code - I need to break up results into several files

Tags: python, csv, writer

Im a php developer but learning python now.

I'm scraping some info and the result list is massive: 150,000+ lines.

The following code does work however, the writer or script seems to choke at around 10,000 lines.

I want to split up the results and have the writer write several csv files of 10,000 lines rather than try to write all results into one file.

In php id do this using a counter variable and stop writing current file, start writing new file with new name.

However, in still learning the syntax for python.

Please can somebody point me along the right lines?

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
while True:
        # preOffset = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")            ## Scroll Content
        # if driver.find_element_by_class_name("NoMoreItems"):
        if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='NoMoreItems']"):
            break
        # print(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;"))
    html= driver.page_source                                                                ## Get HTML Source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')                                                      ## Parse to BS4

        tag = soup.find('div', {'id': 'members'})                   ## Find desire DIV

    tag = tag.find('div', {'class': 'ListContainer'})                       ## Get List container
    # for achr in tag.finAll('a'):
    #     print(achr.string)
    
    with open('members.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvfile:                 ## Initialize the CSV

        # Column of csv file
        column_name = ['Name', 'URL']                                                ## Define Column Name and URL
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=column_name)                            
        writer.writeheader()                                                                ## Header Write
    
        for link in tag.findAll('a'):                                                       ## Find each Anchor tag contains Name
            link = link
            if link.string != None:
                writer.writerow({
                    'Name': link.string,
                    'URL': link["href"]
                })
```

Comment: Ant reason why you are forcing `newline=''`?

Comment: @taras https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3

Comment: There's no inherent limit in Python on the number of rows that can be written to a csv file.  I'd suggest checking that the script is actually finding all the expected data.

Comment: @snakecharmerb It is finding all the data, i sit back and watch it and when it stops, i can continue scrolling manually, exposing rest of results without any apparrent reason for it having stopped

Comment: Beware, indentation does matter in Python. The shown code has inconsistent indentation and is hard to read because of that...

Comment: BTW, I cannot imagine why the script would decide to stop writing into a csv file while it would still have available data. I would instead suspect the soup to contain more than one ListContainer div. Said differently, the script wrote all the content of `tag.find_all('a')` but a part of the expected data was elsewhere.

Comment: If you want to use a counter, you can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function:  `for idx, link in enumerate(tag.findAll('a')):`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Ive found the culprit. The list i was trying to scrape has a built in limit of 10K. I should've known.
Thanks again.